# Find the length and direction of $u \times v$ and $v \times u$

Tags: calculus, vector-spaces, determinant, cross-product

So I was given two vectors:
$u=-8i- 2j- 4k$, and  $v=2i+2j+k$.

I was able to figure out the cross product of $u\times v$ which is $6i-12k$,
and $v \times u$ which is $-6i+12k$.

However, I need help finding the length and direction.

Your help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

The length is $$\sqrt{(-6)^2+(12)^2}$$
 and the direction is
$$n=\frac{-6i+12k}{\sqrt{(-6)^2+(12)^2}}$$

Comment: Do you still face any problem with this answer?